# Detect when the user unlocks the workstation

Tags: node.js, winapi, electron, node-ffi

I'm trying to detect when a user unlocks their workstation. The following code attempts to register the window to receive session change messages using WTSRegisterSessionNotification(). Supposedly after this I can listen for WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE which can contain WTS_SESSION_UNLOCK as a param.

Issue: Currently WTSRegisterSessionNotification() always returns false.

Anyone know how I can achieve this? I'm on Windows 10 btw.

```
var {remote} = require('electron');
var ffi = require('ffi');
var winctl = require('winctl');

var NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS = 1;
var WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE = parseInt('0x02B1', 16);

var hwnd = remote.getCurrentWindow().getNativeWindowHandle();

var wtsapi32 = ffi.Library('wtsapi32', {
  'WTSRegisterSessionNotification': [ 'bool', [ 'int', 'int' ] ]
});

// Attempt to register
var isregistered = wtsapi32.WTSRegisterSessionNotification(hwnd, NOTIFY_FOR_ALL_SESSIONS);

console.log(isregistered); // <----- RETURNS 0...?
```

IInspectable recommended GetLastError().
This is not something supported by node-ffi unfortunately.
https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/issues/261

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383841.aspx): *"If the function succeeds, the return value is TRUE. Otherwise, it is FALSE. **To get extended error information, call [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360.aspx).**"*

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. Looks like that isn't an option when using node-ffi unfortunately. I modified the question to include it though just to make sure. Also found this: https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/issues/261

Comment: Huh.  And someone even went to the trouble of fixing the problem, and the fix never got incorporated into the project.  I'm afraid that means you're flying blind.  Perhaps you could write a simple C DLL that calls WTSRegisterSessionNotification on your behalf and returns the error code?

Comment: I'll wait a bit longer in case someone else has encountered this before. If nobody can help then I'll do what you recommended. Thanks Harry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up giving up on this. I verified that the HWND was correct but it still wouldn't work for whatever reason. I ended up writing a small function in C# and executed it from within node/electron using node-edge.

Comment: Any chance you can share the approach with c# + node-edge? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `winctl.GetActiveWindow` to get a HWND because you don't actually know which window is active. As far as I can tell GetActiveWindow calls `GetForegroundWindow` internally and that is insane for two reasons:

1. GetForegroundWindow returns the foreground window on the users desktop and could be a window in another application.
2. Windows has an actual function named GetActiveWindow and it is not the same as calling GetForegroundWindow.

Create a hidden native window somehow or use a window provided by electron (`GetTopLevelNativeWindow` perhaps?)

`GetLastError` returns the wrong value because you are calling it too late. There is a thick layer of stuff between you and the native Windows function and something is calling `SetLastError` before you regain control. The 'ffi' library needs a way to specify that you want it to call GetLastError on your behalf immediately after calling the requested function.

And finally, a Windows `BOOL` is int sized and I'm guessing node.js treats it as a byte?

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I switched to using the getNativeWindowHandle() function provided by Electron. I also tried setting the return type to int instead of bool but it doesn't make a difference. Still no luck.

Comment: Things to try: Call the IsWindow Windows function to verify that the handle is valid. Call GetWindowThreadProcessId to verify that the HWND is in the same process as GetCurrentProcessId. Run it in a debugger so you can figure out the true error code.

Comment: Thanks. I verified that the handle was valid but it still would not work. Ended up writing a C# method which I executed using node-edge.

Comment: But did you verify that the hwnd is in the same process with GetWindowThreadProcessId?